# Do Tile Servers typically store every tile for every zoom level?

Tags: openstreetmap, web-mapping, tiles

As I understand, a basic tile server provides raster image tiles for different zoom levels. To cover the world, it requires 1 tile at zoom level 0, 4 at zoom level 1, 4<sup>n</sup> for zoom level n. These are billions and billions of images that need to be stored in total for zoom levels 0 to 19.

**My question is**: Do tile servers typically in fact store all of these images? If not, how do they cover the whole world at every zoom level with tiles?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, they don't store every tile. There are several reasons for this:

- Size: Storing all tiles for all zoom levels would require more than 50 TB storage (source: [Tile Disk Usage](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_disk_usage))
- Gain: Typically, only 1.79% of all tiles are actually viewed since many just contain water or other uninteresting regions (source: [Tile Disk Usage](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_disk_usage))
- Computational costs: Pre-rendering all tiles would take a really long time.

Typically, tile servers pre-render some low-zoom tiles (let's say zoom levels 0-12) because they take long to render and will be viewed by many users. For higher zoom levels tiles are rendered on the fly and then cached for a certain time.